# React Derived Props

Tags: reactjs, redux

Simple overview: consider the following structure:

- App (Holds `users` in State)
- Form (`users` passed as `props`, stored locally `this.state = { data: this.props.data }`)

  - Form Row (`user`)
  - Form Row (`user`)
  - Form Row (`user`)

When a row is updated, the `state` of `Form` is updated. This is so I can manage the data on the `Form` independently of `App state`. I can then control saving the data to the `App state` when user clicks on "Save" or "Add" buttons, etc. I don't want App's state to be updated immediately, however, it seems as it's updated, it flows back to App's state. I tried the spread operator to copy data instead--no go.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/MrCGates/pen/YzXYMEv

If you look at this example, it will NOT update the Main display of state, however, if you inspect, the actual state IS modified. Although this is fine for display, I need to have it only save state when the user clicks on a "SAVE" button. Currently, I have my app working correctly, except for the fact, that when we update row #2, any changes in rows #1 and #3 get updated as well because I take Main's state, find row #2, and update. Well, #1 and 32 are updated in state, so it's updating the entire state basically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't necessarily like the technique, but I was able to fix this with:

this.state { data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.props.data)) };

The problem was, copying an array will copy as reference, even with spread, map, etc. Using JSON... creates a deep value copy.